# IIS 7.5 handles RESTful POST differently than other servers

Tags: wcf, http, rest, iis, iis-7.5

I make a RESTful POST to an IIS 7.5 server and it cannot see the body:

```
HttpClient httpclient =  new DefaultHttpClient();     
ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
String response = "";

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(request.getHost());                        

for(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Header header : request.getHeaders()){
    httppost.setHeader(header.getKey(), header.getValue());
}

if(requestBody.length()>0){
      // append the body data to the post
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      sb.append(requestBody);
      StringEntity stringentity = new StringEntity(sb.toString(), HTTP.UTF_8);
      httppost.setEntity(stringentity);                             
}

// hit the server
response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);


// clean up 
httppost = null;

return response;
```

It can see the headers, but is **never able to see the body entity**.

`requestBody` is just a simple string.

Using the exact same code, body and headers and pointing this POST to another server runnning IIS 6.0 or Apache Tomcat 7, both can see and extract the headers and body without issue.

What is IIS 7.5 looking for that it cannot see the body? Do I need to craft the post differently?

reference:

```
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
```

**Related post:** 
My counterpart working on the IIS side of things has [posted his WCF code](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataservices/thread/7853b14a-91cb-4c65-ad2d-d0362e9e7646) on MSDN.

Comment: What exactly are you looking at on the server? IIS logs, WCF code, etc?

Comment: They are using Wireshark to analyze the data coming in - there is no body to speak of at the point where Wireshark gets the post data.

Comment: You'll have to post the headers in both cases.

Comment: How about from your client? Did you try to inspect the raw request on your client machine ?

Comment: @Rajesh Yes, the request looks as expected.  I believe at this point that it's an IIS 7+ configuration issue.  Now, it's a matter of determining how it should be configured to handle the request properly.

Comment: Can you try to get the raw request from the client machine that is being posted to IIS 6 and then use Fiddler or Wireshark to perform the same operation with the raw request to IIS 7.5

Comment: @Rejesh As stated in the post, I am working from a non-microsoft system.  I have no direct access to that system.  These tools only work on Microsoft systems, so specifically, I cannot do as you ask of me.  I am fairly certain at this point it is NOT the post but the IIS 7.5 server configuration that's the problem.